# Taking screenshot in python when system is in locked state

Tags: python, window, locking, screenshot

I have created a python script that perform some operation on browser and take a screenshot of it. 
When system is not locked my script is working fine. 
But when system is locked it is taking a screenshot of my locked screen not browser. 
How to take a screenshot of browser when system is locked?

I am using:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32com.client as win32
import re

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

chromedriver = 'C:\Python27\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
link=driver.get('http://10.113.174.197/testlink/login.php?
note=logout&viewer=')

username = "xyz"
password = "xyz"

def login():
    inputid = driver.find_element_by_id('tl_login')
    inputid.send_keys(username)
    inputpass = driver.find_element_by_name('tl_password')
    inputpass.send_keys(password)
    signin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/input')
    signin.click()
    time.sleep(3)

def testreport():

  driver.get("http://10.113.174.197/testlink/lib/results/resultsByTesterPerBuild.php?format=0&tplan_id=537")
#driver.get('http://10.113.174.194/testlink/lib/results/resultsGeneral.php?format=0&tplan_id=125194')

def screenshot():
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save('C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads\screenshot.png')
    img.show()

def mail():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'xyz@gmail'
    mail.Subject = 'xyz '
    attachment =mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads\screenshot.png")
    mail.Attachments.Add('C:\Users\MA299445\Downloads\screenshot.png')
    mail.Send()




 if __name__ == '__main__':
    login()
    testreport()
    time.sleep(3)
    screenshot()
    time.sleep(3)
    mail()
```

Environment : 
Python 2.3
Windows 10

Comment: give your full code or this is it ??

Comment: @manan_kalariya : I have added my full code please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to capture the screenshot. It works even if the screen is locked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
#removes the file if it already exists
try:
    os.remove('E:\dhd.png')
except WindowsError: 
    #print("no file found")
    pass
# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession")
driver.save_screenshot('e:\dhd.png')
driver.quit()
```